# Are mysql events running in separate connections?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am wondering if [MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) launches it's events in different connections. I do want to use temporary tables in the Stored Procedure, and temporary tables are unique per connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheduler will run as a separate process, which will open connections to the database as if it was just a different application.  After an event is complete the connection will close, with the next event opening a new connection.

It is possible that connection pooling will be used, which may mean a connection is recycled for very closely occuring events.  But it will be cleaned up anyway.

As far as I know.

In short, treat it as if each event has absolutely no knowledge of the others.

Comment: Any reference on this in an official paper?

Comment: No, just experience (with MySQL, and a few other RDBMSs).  If the sessions (or more importantly, the session states) propegated between events, behaviour of any individual event would be dependant on preceding events, their order, etc, etc.  It would be extremely suprising to me that this would be allowed, or atleast intended.  It seems persuasive to say that independant events should execute independantly.

Comment: The only recomendations that I can make are that if you wish to persist data, to use a persistant store (real table), or if you want mutiple events to interact, it may be that they should be coded into a single event.